# How to merge several tracked documents into one?

Tags: microsoft-word, lotus-notes, microsoft-word-2003

We need to send a document to 21 receivers for review. They will use the tracking function to add comments and changes.

We will then receive 21 documents and to simplify the process we would like to import all the changes and comments into one single document. Then use the tools provided by Word to track and implement these changes.

Unfortunately, we have to use Lotus Notes as mail system and can't use the built in mail function to send out for review.

Is there a way to achieve this? (collect all the tracking information from several documents into one?).

Comment: Although it may depend on the versions involved, you really should be able to configure your systems to use Lotus Notes with the builtin mail function in Word.  You may want to consider adding that as a separate question over on ServerFault.